# Is there an algorithm for temporal characteristics of verbs (Zeno Vendler's paper)?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, computer-science

Is there an algorithm for finding temporal characteristics of verbs? Meaning if it's an "event", "accomplishment", "achievement" or "state"? As described in Zeno Vendler's paper "Verbs and Times"?

http://semantics.uchicago.edu/kennedy/classes/s07/events/vendler57.pdf

Or maybe someone has an idea of what would be the best way to implement such thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you specifically want an algorithm or would you accept lexical resources which at least tell you how a particular verb typically behaves? If you had such a dictionary, you could use that + some basic rules as a first pass.

Comment: lexical resources will be fine too, please post. looks like plug-and-play algorithm does not really exist.

Comment: Not a real answer yet, but [this paper](http://utdallas.academia.edu/ChrisIrwinDavis/Papers/1341342/A_Framework_for_Representing_Event_Semantics_of_Verb_Word_Senses) discusses adding event semantics at the top of the WordNet hierarchy and allowing them to propagate down the subtrees to get event/situation classes for a lot of verbs pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, there is no way to do this without the use of a database. The "algorithm" itself would then be a union of the **structure of the database** and the **queries** made to it.

For example, a relational database which had a table of English words, each two columns: word and 1 or more parts of speech, is the most basic language processing database conceivable. A more complex one would also have a verb table with two columns, word, and "temporal characteristics".

As an example, the word "be" always describes a state. Therefore, a program that sees the word be (or its conjugations: is, are, was, etc.) can immediately recognize the clause as describing a state-of-being. Obviously, the word accomplish will immediately denote an accomplishment, and "achieve" will always denote an achievement. But don't forget that out of the four categories you listed, only "state" and "event" are mutually exclusive (with the exception of a present participle such as in the sentence "An event is taking place."). Other than that, a state can also be an accomplishment or achievement ("I am an Olympic gold medalist.") and so can an event ("I graduate tomorrow.").

Accomplishment and achievement are also **subjective** terms and depend on the sensibilities of the speaker and reader alike. Words like "achieve", "accomplished" and "succeeded" are deliberate expressions of a feeling of achievement, and can therefore always be categorized as such. However, this is a priori information, and would therefore require a relational database to be realized.

Finally, some words' "temporal characteristics" change depending the **other words in the sentence**. For example, in the sentence "I smell good.", "smell" is a state-of-being verb. In the sentence "I smell bacon.", it is an action verb. These kinds of verbs are action verbs when followed by a noun (transitive), state-of-being verbs when followed by an adjective (predicate nominative), and action verbs when followed by neither (intransitive). A parser would therefore have to inspect the words that follow it in the sentence, one as a noun or adjective, and from that recognize the verb's role in the sentence. This is a joint effort between the database knowing the parts of speech of each word, and the algorithm being able to parse the sentence correctly (and simply knowing that it needs to parse it at all).

This is just a brief overview of lexographical computing, and just my knowledge on the subject. There's a lot more to it and obviously, populating a database with words and their parts of speech, definitions, roles, etc. is tedious. There may exist databases pre-populated with the information that a lexographical computer scientist would need to implement such a system (but I don't claim to know where one would find them).

Hope I've helped, and good luck!